# organize assistance in mysql: tables VS columns

Tags: mysql, performance, user-tracking

### Reason

I am organising a system to keep the track of assistance/punctuality in a music band weekly. We are around 40 people, and I would like how should I organize it. I need to save 2 things, hour of arrival, and reason.
I also have in the database all members that were part of the band, and I mark if they are currently active. I don't want to erase data from any member, but new members may get into the band.

### Options

1. Create a table for each user, and a entry for each day, referencing what time did him arrive and the reason:

   - 3 columns
   - 1 row/week
   - 40 tables (or more)
2. Create a table for reasons and a table for arrivals:

   - 1 initial + 1 column/week
   - 40 rows per table (or more)
   - 2 tables
3. Create a table for each day:

   - 3 column per table
   - 40 row/table (or more)
   - 1 table/week

So... which is more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

### BandMembers Table:

BandMemberId (integer),
FirstName (varchar),
LastName (varchar),
DateInserted (Date/Time),
Active (boolean/bit)

### Attendance Table:

AttendanceId (integer),
BandMemberId (integer),
Arrival (Date/Time),
ReasonId (integer)

UPDATED WITH REASON TABLE:

### Reason Table:

ReasonId (integer),
Reason (varchar)

This way you can join Attendance table to BandMember table on BandMemberId.

---

**UPDATED 5/25 NEW REQUIREMENTS:**

Since you need to store information about each rehearsal/meeting, I'd do it like this:

### BandMember Table:

BandMemberId (integer), FirstName (varchar), LastName (varchar), DateInserted (Date/Time), Active (boolean/bit)

### EventTable:

EventId(int), EventName (varchar), EventDate (datetime), EventTypeId (int)

### EventType Table:

EventTypeId (int), EventDescription(varchar)

### BandMemberEvent Table:

BandMemberEventId (int), BandMemberId(int), EventTypeId(int), TimeArrived(date/time), ReasonId (int), EventId (int)

### Reason Table:

ReasonId (int), Reason(varchar)

Comment: Nice. You can add that one can change `reason` to `reasonId` and have a separate `Reason` table, since the possible reasons to attend are probably repeatable, like `('write a song', 'test new quitar', 'jam', 'hang out', etc)`

Comment: @dolphy I was just asking about attendance, I have another table with all data (thats why all columns are +1 default) 1:1.

Comment: What I want to know is what is more efficiente in mysql, to have a table with lots of rows, a table with lots of columns, or a lot of tables

Comment: @txomon You're going about this the wrong way. You shouldn't be adding columns as a normal process of your application, just adding new rows. That's how it's meant to work.

Comment: @txomon, JohnD is correct.  You want each table to represent some entity.  So in your case you have 3: band member, attendance, and reason for attendance.  Each one of those gets a unique id.  in the Attendance table, you get an Id to recognize each band member and an Id to represent a reason.  I'd suggest you take a look at a [SQL tutorial on the web](http://www.firstsql.com/tutor.htm)  or possibly read the [O'Reilly book Learning SQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007270/)

Comment: @dolphy there is a problem in that solution, I am not storing at which hour he should have been

Comment: @txomon - so then all you need to add is a column to the attendance table.  You can call it ExpectedTime or something like that.

Comment: but they are going to be particular days, shouldn't I create another table with days?

Comment: @txomon you can use the datetime data type for the column which will include the day month year and time. Unless you have a set schedule or something like that. Perhaps I don't fully understand the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @dolphy assistance if for concerts, meetings and rehearses. We have one each Sunday, so what I was asking about if I should make a table in which I store which was the hour/date they should be there (row/meeting), and reference it from assistance tables.
As there would be a row/(person*day), normalizing days would be also recommended, wouldn't it?

Comment: well, I want to make posible to store information about it, and if that date was a meeting, concert or rehearsal.

If I use a independent table in which I store the date/time and reference it from attendance table, I could group 40 rows by the same date/time, and store information about that date in that linked table.

btw, which type relationship should I mark when making this relationships? mandatory in both sides and identifying relationship?

Thank you for your time

Comment: @dolphy I finally did this [link](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3972/sinttulofx.png) with other names, but I think it aproaches to solution

Comment: As long as you're understanding the table relationships.  Thats what's important.

Comment: @dophy The link I put and what you expained is the same, isn't it? But I think you mistyped bandMemberEvent table, because you are using EventTypeId instead of EventId

Comment: @txomon I should've added EventId as well.  I'll add it in.  EventTypeId will link the type of event it is: 'rehearsal', 'concert'.  Maybe Reason is the same thing??

Comment: @dolphy, sorry for replying so late, I've been in exams. I have been making experiments with your schema disposition, and I finally, put it like this  
http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/5041/structure.png

Comment: @txomon -- Looks good.  Important thing is that you think relational which it seems you are now.